# Is this Wikipedia article about symmetric difference on measure spaces not correct?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

I'm reading about [symmetric difference operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Symmetric_difference_on_measure_spaces) on a $\sigma$-finite measure space from Wikipedia.

---

Using the ideas of measure theory, the separation of measurable sets can be defined to be the measure of their symmetric difference. If $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$, the function
$$
d_{\mu}(X, Y)=\mu(X \triangle Y)
$$
is a **pseudometric** on $\Sigma$. $d_{\mu}$ becomes a **metric** if $\Sigma$ is considered modulo the equivalence relation $X$ $\sim Y$ if and only if $\mu(X \triangle Y)=0$. It is sometimes called Fréchet-Nikodym metric. The resulting metric space is separable if and only if $L^{2}(\mu)$ is separable.

---

**My understanding:** I feel that statement

> ... the function $d_{\mu}(X, Y)=\mu(X \triangle Y)$ is a **pseudometric** on $\Sigma$. $d_{\mu}$ becomes a **metric** ...

may be not correct. This is because there may be $X, Y\in \Sigma$ such that $X \cap Y = \emptyset$ and $\mu(A), \mu(B) = \infty$. It follows that
$$
d_\mu (X, Y) = \mu((X \cup Y) \setminus (X \cap Y)) = \mu(X \cup Y) = \infty.
$$

Could you confirm if my understanding is fine?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Good catch! But it works if $\mu$ is a finite measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that we have to restrict to a subspace of $\Sigma$ such as $\Sigma':=\{X|\mu(X)<\infty\}$. We can establish everything by sending $X$ into its characteristic fundion $1_{X}$. It's easy to see that this is indeed an isometric embedding from $\Sigma'$ to $L^2(\mu)$. And since any measurable function can be approximated by (finite or countable) linear combination of characteristic functions (step functions), it follows easily that $\Sigma'$ is separable iff $L^2(\mu)$ is.

Comment: We have $d_{\mu}(X, Y) = \int 1_{X \triangle Y} \mathrm d \mu =  \int |1_X - 1_Y| \mathrm d \mu$. As such, I feel that the isometric embedding should be from $\Sigma'$ to $L(\mu)$. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Oh, I see. That's right. For functions that assume only $0$ and $1$ such as $1_{X\triangle Y}$, it's the same as its square, hence $L^2$-norm is equal to the $L^1$-norm square-rooted, and I forgot the square-root earlier.